How can my friend tell his mom she can't move back in because she hasn't paid anything except the down payment and closing costs?
My friends mom put down the down payment and closing costs on a house. She hasn't paid anything towards the mortgage, taxes, repairs or bills. She ended up moving to another state with his sister and even there she doesn't drop a dime. The sister has had it and told him shes sending her back. She won't go into assisted living and can't be required to either. He really doesn't want her back but he can't figure his way out,
He's been in the house for 7 years and paid everything. He can't afford to pay her back the down payment and his interest is 3.5% so refinancing is out. She has no will so he gets it when she dies as its a joint ownership with right of survivorship. She has become intolerable and argues with him and his wife daily.
Is there anyway to avoid him from having to let her back in the house? I know living in Florida they protect seniors but he needs protection from her.
They also own the lot next door which was paid by her.(It was really cheap back then)

Is her name on the title (not the mortgage, but the title/deed)?

Yes, she is on both the Deed and the mortgage.  I said tell her there is no equity in the home yet so stay put in Colorado.  He won't be able to get a mortgage  at 3.5% . I was hoping to hear she has to pay half of everything  in the rears before coming back!

"arrears", not the rears, except that nothing appears to be in arrears.

I had "arrears" when I put the question out there. Have to love spellcheck. Thanks. Him and his wife are the nicest couple. I thought she might have to pay her half of the mortgage and taxes after the down payment and closing costs were repaid.

Is your friend paying rent to his mom? Because if he's been living there for 7 years it would be normal for him to have paid her rent. If not then I would expect that more or less the rent he hasn't paid should balance out the mortgage she hasn't paid

He pays everything including the mortgage, taxes all bills and repairs.  She hasn't put in a nickel.  The deed and the mortgage is in both names. Why would he pay her rent??? She lived there for the first 3 years and paid nothing?

Your friend has been making payments on a house that he did not own. That's a nice gift to his mother, but it does not make him the owner.

If they had a rental agreement where he paid enough to cover the mortgage and all bills then it would be her house and they'd have a landlord+tenant arrangement. Tenants pay landlords enough for mortgage taxes bills and repairs and they have no claim to ownership. Why does he think that the fact that he pays the bills directly entitles him to partial ownership of the home?

You've said that her name is on the deed and the mortgage, but is your friend's name on those instruments too? Or just his mom's name?

If you've got the money, you could offer to buy her out. But presumably if you had the money, she wouldn't have had to help with this purchase.

Frame challenge: if your friend doesn't want to live with her, your friend can move out.

I am not a lawyer, and the friend should probably talk to one, but I don't think your friend has a way out of this. If the mother's name is on the deed then she (at least partially) owns the house. He can't legally keep her from moving into a house she owns.
It seems like the mother can't be bought out. So the best way out of this is probably to sell the house, decide on a fair split of the proceeds, and go their separate ways. Your friend will have to move obviously, but then they will be out of this whole obligation. It might be a good idea to sell the extra plot as well to totally sever the financial part of this relationship.
Personally, I think it was bad judgement on their part to accept all this financial help from their mother and not expect she would want anything in return.

This isn't really a "personal finance" question but more a legal question and a family relations question, but whatever.
Legally: You said that her name is on the deed. Is there anything more specific than that about their mutual rights? If not, then she has as much legal right to the house as he does. He can't tell her that she's not allowed to live in her own house. If this went so far that they ended up in court, I'm sure a judge would rule that he either has to let her move in, or has to buy out her share.
Ethically: You said that she paid the down payment and closing costs. Presumably he couldn't afford the house without that help or he wouldn't have taken it. So his mother made it possible for him to get a house, and now he wants to lock her out of it? That seems a little ... inconsiderate. Furthermore, how much was the down payment and closing costs? If she paid a 20% down payment, and he's been paying off a 30 year mortgage for 7 years, he's likely put in less money than she did. On day 1 of this deal she had 20% equity and he had 0%. Maybe he's now up to 15% or so. She may well have more invested than he does. Depending on interest rates, maintenance costs, etc.
I can understand not wanting to share a house with his mother. I have no idea what she is like. Maybe she's obnoxious and annoying. Maybe she had medical problems and she would be a burden. Or maybe she's the most wonderful person in the world. I don't know. But he took her money and now she's asking to get some use out of her investment and he's trying to say no? That seems pretty rude.

And neither OP nor his friend can see that.

I agree 100%  that he should never have taken it from her. They're both on the deed and the mortgage. There should have been terms and conditions that had stipulations in it. She has no will so I said just deal with her.

Yes. I guess the moral of this story is: Even when it's family, unless you're just giving someone a gift, have a written agreement what the rights and responsibilities of each person are. Otherwise there is a big danger of some kind of disagreement down the road. One person may say, "But I just took it for granted that ..." and the other person says "No, that's not what I intended at all" and it turns in to a big fight. Families have ended up in court over less.

My sister-in-law just ran into some financial problems and asked to borrow money from us. She offered to have a formal agreement for when she would pay us back. I said not to bother. I told her to pay us back when she could and left it at that. If that turns out to be never, well, I've agreed to give her an amount that I can afford to lose. So if it helps her pride to think of it as a loan, fine for her. As far as I'm concerned, it's a gift. I would rather lose the money than end up in court fighting with my sister-in-law over breech of contract.
